# Uploading Image with requests/selenium/pywinauto

Tags: python, selenium, pywinauto

Am trying to automate some postings on a couple different websites. Basically fill out my form and upload them to 3 sites with Selenium or requests. The image upload on this site opens a new window and asks you to specify the file path, or you can drag and drop the files. Here is what is looks like.  [image: Here is what it looks like]

And without CSS here is what it looks like.

[image]

I abandoned requests earlier thinking there was no way I was going to be able to do anything with it. Moved to selenium and can click on the button and open the window but cannot actually place an image to upload in there. I have tried pywinauto and keep getting ElementNotVisible. I am having a hard time looking through the docs to find what to actually do. Where to go from here?

Comment: you can directly send the file path to upload the files rather using pywinauto, provided the browse button have '<intput type="file">. Can you please share the html of the browse button parent (make sure you have all the children of parent element when copied the html)

Comment: @supputuri here is the html, let me know if you need more. It is input type=file. What would I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below.

```
eleBrowse = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@type='file']'))) 
# replace the path below with the one which you want to upload. If you want to send multiple files use comma as separator.  
eleBrowse.send_keys("path")
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. Thank you so much. That was much much easier than I was expecting.